# .transition() breaks my difference chart

Tags: d3.js, transition

For some reason, adding a transition breaks my two clipPaths. This works perfectly:

```
// Append path first
var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);
var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
gEnter.append("clipPath").attr("class", "above").attr("id", "clip-above").append("path");
gEnter.append("clipPath").attr("class", "below").attr("id", "clip-below").append("path");

// Later, attach data
var g = svg.select("g")
g.select("#clip-above path").attr("d", area.y0(0));
g.select("#clip-below path").attr("d", area.y0(height));
```

But if I add a transition, the entire area is just colored by `area-below`:

```
// Later, attach data
var g = svg.select("g")
g.select("#clip-above path").transition().duration(500).attr("d", area.y0(0));
g.select("#clip-below path").transition().duration(500).attr("d", area.y0(height));
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in `d3.v2`. Always be sure to update!